# Baby names not working

Tags: java

Hi i have a program that doesnt seem to be registering. I am fairly new so I would appreciate any help and there might be stupid mistakes made :/
But the point of the program is the enter a name and then find the name in a file called names.txt and then show the popularity of the name throughout the century. I currently have a program that doesnt seem to be working. Help Please

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Babynames{
   public static void main (String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{


     Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("names.txt")); 
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What name would you like to search up: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(name);
        String thisname = lineScan.next();


        if (name.equals(name))
        {
        while (lineScan.hasNextInt())
           {
           int next = lineScan.nextInt();
           for (int i = 1900; i <=2000; i+=10)
              {
              System.out.print(i + next);
              }
           }
        }




     else
           {
         System.out.println("File not found!  Try again: ");
             String filename = input.nextLine();
             Scanner lineScan2 = new Scanner(name);
            }
     }
}
```

---

**Edit**
it just asks for the name and after that the program ends

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Could you please say what it is that is malfunctioning? Does the code compile? If so, does it crash when you run it?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663689/baby-names-java-program?rq=1) question, and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) meta Stackoverflow post concerning homework. We're happy to help, but you have to help us help you.

Comment: Does it set your toaster on fire? Please give us the details so we can help you better?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It actually set *my* toaster on fire. I just spent 5 minutes putting out the kitchen fire.

Comment: Remotely and randomly setting peoples toasters on fire. Genius.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, but it just asks for the name and after that the program ends

Comment: @BrianRoach: I knew it would do this!

Comment: @user3051165: question edited and your information has been placed in the edit.

Comment: Your code looks like a Java version of "stream of consciousness". I think that you need to primarily re-think your program logic. A better exercise would be for you to think through the logical steps necessary to solve something like this, the smallest steps you can think of, and the order these steps should be in, including repeating your steps (loops), and only *after* doing that, translate it into Java code. In particular, look at your nesting your while loop inside of the if block. Should the if block be called only once as you've written it? or multiple times?

Comment: Does it write to the file names.txt? even if it's one name?

Comment: yea, its supposed to be send to a file called names.txt

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment seems to be:

- Accept a baby name as input
- find that name in a file that includes some information about that name
- output the result which includes the info about the name.

From your code, I'm making an educated guess that a line in your file looks like:

> name value value value value value value value value value value value

Where the values represent the popularity of the name 1900 - 2000 by decade (11 values)

So, your program would need to:

- Get the user input (name) from `System.in` using a `Scanner` .
- Open the file
- Loop, reading a line from the file

  - [Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the line by space (`" "`) into a `String[] array`
  - Compare the first element (`array[0]`) to see if it's your name

    - if it is, go through the rest of the array and output the values

Comment: Give him the logic, let him write the code. Well done. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm fine with this level of "help me with my homework" ... can't stand it when people post complete code (usually with no instruction) to get rep. Doesn't help anyone in the end.